# How to remove/select rows in matrix given external condition from another array with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix and a truth table array for this matrix like so :

```
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 5]])
truth_table = np.array([0, 1, 0])
```

The goal is to keep only the rows in the matrix where the truth table is equal to one, in this case only `[[2, 3, 4]]`.

The matrix has as many row as the truth table has elements.

In any other language I would do this :

```
results = np.array([])
for i in range(truth_table.size) :
  if(truth_table[i] == 1)
    results.append(matrix[i])
```

The problem is that the matrix can be enormous and for loops are not optimized in Python for this sort of problem and thus can take a really long time to execute.

I am sure there is a better way to do this using numpy but I can't seem to find the solution.

Comment: Convert truth_table to boolean array and then index into matrix. More info - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your `truth` table has `dtype=bool` then you can just do `matrix[truth_table]`

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array([[1, 2, 2], [2, 3, 4], [4, 3, 5]])
truth_table = np.array([0, 1, 0], dtype=bool)
# or truth_table = np.array([False, True, False])
print(matrix[truth_table])
# prints [[2, 3, 4]]
```